# How do I get id from table1 to tabel2?

Tags: php, mysql

```
if ( isset( $_POST['add'] ) ) {

      $id = $sql['id'];
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id IN (id1, id2, ..., idn)";

      $insert = "INSERT INTO table1(firstname,lastname,birthday,numbers,numbers2,aadress,vali) VALUES('$firstname','$lastname','$birthday','$number','$capture_field_vals1','$aadress','$vali')";


      $insert2 = "INSERT INTO table2(number1, number2, number3, number4, number5, number6, number7, number8, number9, number10) VALUES('" . $capture_field_vals[0] . "','" . $capture_field_vals[1] . "','" . $capture_field_vals[2] . "','" . $capture_field_vals[3] . "','" . $capture_field_vals[4] . "','" . $capture_field_vals[5] . "','" . $capture_field_vals[6] . "','" . $capture_field_vals[7] . "','" . $capture_field_vals[8] . "','" . $capture_field_vals[9] . "')";
      $insert3 = "INSERT INTO table2 (contactID) VALUES ('$id')";
                    //$sql.= " WHERE id = '$id' ";


        if(mysql_query($insert)) {
            //echo "$eesnimi $perenimi ON $aastad AASTAT VANA";
        } else {
          //echo "Cannot Insert";
          }
  if(mysql_query($insert2)) {echo "KORRAS";} else {echo "Cannot Insert";}
  if(mysql_query($insert3)){echo 'KORRAS';}  else{echo 'Cannot Insert';}
}
```

Question is, how do I get table1 ID into table2 contactID ?

I tried a lot with different ways, but no output..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function: [mysqli_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Just do the first insert and request the insert ID afterwards:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO table1(firstname,lastname,birthday,numbers,numbers2,aadress,vali) VALUES('$firstname','$lastname','$birthday','$number','$capture_field_vals1','$aadress','$vali')";
if(mysqli_query($insert)) {
  $insertID = mysqli_insert_id();
  $insert2 = "INSERT INTO table2(number1, number2, number3, number4, number5, number6, number7, number8, number9, number10) VALUES('" . $capture_field_vals[0] . "','" . $capture_field_vals[1] . "','" . $capture_field_vals[2] . "','" . $capture_field_vals[3] . "','" . $capture_field_vals[4] . "','" . $capture_field_vals[5] . "','" . $capture_field_vals[6] . "','" . $capture_field_vals[7] . "','" . $capture_field_vals[8] . "','" . $capture_field_vals[9] . "')";
  $insert3 = "INSERT INTO table2 (contactID) VALUES ('$insertID')";
  mysqli_query($insert2);
  mysqli_query($insert3);
}
```

BTW: You should use mysqli_* functions rather than mysql_* as they are deprecated.

Comment: But this way I dont get table1 id :(

Comment: Table1 id is AUTO_INCREMENT, I dont insert it myself

Comment: Sure you do. You insert a record in table1 and use mysqli_insert_id() to request the ID of the just inserted record. Being AUTO_INCREMENT is not a problem here.

Comment: Ou yes, its working Sorry, just mysqli not work, i dont know why, but I replaced mysqli with mysql and then works ;)

Answer (score 0):

Erki,

mysql_insert_id() returns the id of the last inserted record, is that of any help?

Comment: Nope, i need form  table1 ID, What is AI